# How to draw a character at a random place on the screen - c++

Tags: c++, windows

Sorry about the dumb question, but is there a way to draw a character at a random place on the screen without using any "heavy" graphics libraries?

Thanks,
Li

Comment: What do you mean by a character? You mean an ASCII character, for example an asterisk? Or do you mean a game character, for example Batman? (I'm guessing the first...)

Comment: in console ? on the Windows Desktop ? above any other window ? Inside your application's window ? other ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try writing directly to video RAM at address B800:0000 (see [Bios Memory Map](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/bios_data_area.html)).

Comment: Oh wow, this still works? I used to do that when writing Turbo Pascal programs on my 80286 :-)

Comment: No, actually I was expected to get voted down: I'm feeling rather nostalgic today!

Answer (score 3):

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
RECT rc;
rc.left = 0;
rc.right = 100;
rc.top = 0;
rc.bottom = 100;
DrawText(hdc, L"Bla", 3, &rc, 0);
```

Am I helping a virus programmer here?

Comment: No :) You're helping a poor computer science student :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a console application:

```
#include "windows.h"

void gotoxy(int x, int y) 
{ 
COORD coord; 
coord.X = x; coord.Y = y; 
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_H ANDLE), coord); 
}

void PaintcharOnRandomLocation(const char c)
{
srand(0);
int x = rand(79);
int y = rand(24);
gotoxy(x,y);
putch(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's in console, [1](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=209526) and [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686025.aspx)